# Написать функцию которая принимает 2 параметра: число часов и число минут и выводит число секунд на экран

Tags: python

Помогите решить задачку, не могу сообразить, нужно написать функцию которая принимает 2 параметра: число часов и число минут и выводит число секунд на экран. Кусочек кода который дан:

```py
def get_seconds(hours, minutes):
    seconds = None
    # Наша логика
    print(seconds)
```

Comment: Вопросы наводящие вам: сколько секунд в минуте? сколько минут в часе? сколько секунд в часе? Попробуйте решить задачу сначала отдельно для минут и отдельно для часов.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Число часов на 3600, чтобы перевести его в секунды, и затем умножаем число минут на 60, чтобы перевести его в секунды

```
def get_seconds(hours, minutes):
    seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60
    print(seconds)
```

Comment: Не нужно простейшие задачи делать за кого-то. Человек так ничему не научится. Тут ведь нет никакой зауми, которую невозможно самому человеку понять.